# Get balance in fast node by Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, balances

Is it possible to get account Balance in fast node with Geth ?
and what is the size of fast node currently?

Comment: There is no Fast nodes in Ethereum. There are Full Nodes and Archival Nodes. 
Fast is a sync mode, not a type of mode. When your Node fast-syncs it will become Full Node.

Comment: the size is 450GB

Comment: a Node doing a Fast sync can't give you any balances

Comment: I'll add that a node in fast mode once it has finished synchronizing it will be able to answer balances correctly.